# "style.display = 'flex/none'" not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, styles, display

So I thought it would be pretty simple to implement an if statement to have an element appear or disappear at the click of a button.
After a couple of hours now, I have not gotten further than getting the element to disappear. It registers the second click(tested with a console.log), but the display property does not change back to 'flex'.

I've also already tried different variations of 'getElementById' and 'querySelector' during my sentence.

```
const edit = document.getElementById('edit-btn');
const fill = document.querySelector('#filler');

edit.addEventListener('click', popInOut(fill))

function popInOut(e){
    if(e.style.display=='flex'){
        e.style.display='none'
    }else if(e.style.display=='none'){
        e.style.display='flex'
    }
}
```

The 'filler' element is a bootstrap column with this styling.

```
#filler{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1c1f22;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    height:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey it is your query selector which is causing the problem
and also you can use your filler directly in function because its declared
in global scope

```js
   const edit = document.getElementById("edit-btn");
   const filler = document.getElementById("filler");
    
    
    edit.addEventListener("click", fix);
    
    function fix() {
      if (filler.style.display === "none") {
        filler.style.display = "flex";
      } else {
        filler.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#filler {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  gap: 1rem;
}

#filler div:nth-child(even) {
  background: turquoise;
}

#filler div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="style.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="filler">
        <div>Hare krishna</div>
        <div>Radhe Shyam</div>
        <div>Sita Ram</div>
      </div>
      <button id="edit-btn">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could've sword I tried this in the first place. But it worked, Thanks!